# How to print the base file name using find in Unix?

Tags: find

I have been trying to print out the base file names using find in Unix. 
To simply print out the file names the command I have been using is this

```
find . -type f -name \*.out -print
```

It prints out the full path qualified path names. But I want the base file names only. That is why I have been trying the following command

```
find . -type f -name \*.out -exec basename {}
```

But it errors out and displays

```
find: incomplete statement
```

Please help me through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missing `;` character to terminate primary expression (See [POSIX find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05)):

```
find . -type f -name \*.out -exec basename {} ';'
```

The reason you must escape, or quote `;` because it's your shell list separator. You must make your shell treat it literally. `\;`, `';'` or `";"` all work well.

But this solution will call `basename` for each file found, make it slow. If file names don't contain newline, you can:

```
find . -type f -name '*.out' | sed -e 's#.*/##'
```

If you have [GNU coreutils version >= 8.16](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS), or you are on OSX, you can use [basename -a](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/basename.1.html):

```
find . -type f -name '*.out' -exec basename -a -- {} +
```

Comment: Not only OSX `find` supports `-a`. GNU `find` does it as well.

Comment: @jlliagre: I guess you mean `basename` instead of `find`. And at least in Debian Wheezy, (GNU coreutils) 8.13, it doesn't.

Comment: That was `basename` indeed, not `find`. That looks to be a recent addition  as this option is supported at least with GNU coreutils 8.20.

Comment: @jlliagre: The change was made in version 8.16, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your command is missing a semicolon at the end, to terminate the `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name \*.out -exec basename {} \;
```

But that command will run quite slowly because it forks an external process and calls `basename` for each and every match. If your find supports the `-printf` option, you might want to use that instead:

```
find . -type f -name \*.out -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: That sounds good and works pretty well but why is that ; needed after all and why do we need to escape it ?

Comment: For why it's needed, that's clearly documented in the manpage. Please read it. It's how `find` knows where your command ends. For why it needs to be escaped, it's a shall metacharacter.

Answer (score 2):

you left `\;`

```
 find . -type f -name \*.out -exec basename {} \;
```

If your file paths don't contain newline characters, you can also use `awk`:

```
find . -type f -name \*.out -print | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'
```